# Изменить порядок символов в списке на основании другого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как вывести элементы из первого списка, на основании второго, в том порядке как указаны индексы.

```
Spisok1=['a','b','c','d','e']     #1 список

Spisok2=[2,0,1,4,3]               #2 список

?
?
?

Spisok3=['c','a','b','e','d'].   <——— надо получить
```

Comment: `Spisok3 = [Spisok1[i] for i in Spisok2]`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @andreymal, оформите комментарий как ответ, а то замудренный вариант с itemgetter победит :D

Comment: @gil9red, так классно же, функциональненько)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Списковое включение, наверное, самый лучший вариант по читаемости, но можно еще и с помощью [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
s2 = [2, 0, 1, 4, 3]

s3 = list(itemgetter(*s2)(s1))
print(s3)  # ['c', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: И вам спасибо за ответ :D